# Why is variational Bayesian mixture model an alternative to MCMC? What are the similarities?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, mixture-distribution, variational-bayes

Why do people say that a variational Bayesian mixture model could be an alternative to MCMC for clustering? For example see the details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_method.

What is the purpose of the Markov Chain in MCMC? Does it correspond to the beta / Dirichlet distribution in variational Bayesian method? Do I make sense of the probability model described in Markov Chain?

Answer (score 5):

The variational Bayes approach to a Bayesian mixture model, as described in detail in [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_method), is producing a pseudo-posterior distribution on the parameters of the mixture model, including the latent variables $\mathbf{Z}$, by imposing a certain dependence structure (or graphical model) and estimating the hyperparameters of this model by a maximising algorithm akin to the [EM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation-maximization_algorithm).

> **Note:** variational Bayes is a form of (empirical) Bayesian inference, which simplifies the true posterior into a distribution
>   with more independence assumptions. In the current example, the
>   construction of the  variational Bayes approximation relies on an
>   optimisation algorithm that is close to EM, usually employed for
>   maximum likelihood estimation.

Reproducing the equations from that [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_method) we have that
$$q(\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{\pi},\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Lambda}) = q(\mathbf{Z})q(\mathbf{\pi},\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Lambda})$$
means that $\mathbf{Z}$ is given as independent from $(\mathbf{\pi},\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Lambda})$ in the variational Bayes approximation, which is not true for the exact posterior distribution, proportional to $p(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{\pi},\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Lambda})$. When solving the VB equation
$$q^*(\mathbf{Z}) = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{\pi},\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Lambda}}[\ln p(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{\pi},\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Lambda})] + \text{constant} $$
the variational Bayes version of the posterior on the latent variables is of the Multinomial kind
$$q^*(\mathbf{Z}) = \prod_{n=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^K r_{nk}^{z_{nk}}$$
Similarly, the variational Bayes approximation makes the assumption that the posterior on the parameters factorises as
$$q(\mathbf{\pi},\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Lambda})=q(\mathbf{\pi}) \prod_{k=1}^K q(\mathbf{\mu}_k,\mathbf{\Lambda}_k)$$
and the conjugate nature of the prior implies that the variational Bayes posterior is also from the conjugate family. (This is a generic result for variational Bayes approximations in exponential families.)

There is no connection with MCMC, but rather [EM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation-maximization_algorithm), as well-described in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_method): the reason is that the variational Bayes posterior is made of standard distributions, thus does not require simulation, but has hyperparameters, like the $r_{kn}$ above that need derivation by an optimisation program, hence the call to an EM-like algorithm. The only weak similarity is that both MCMC and EM are iterative, but the number of iterations in EM is determined by convergence to the optimum, while the number of iterations in MCMC is unlimited. Furthermore, MCMC operates on the parameter space, while EM operates on the hyperparameter space.

Comment: Xi'an, thanks for explaining. Can I say like this? variational Bayes finds the full posterior distribution using EM over parameters and hyper-parameters. Whereas MCMC takes a more direct approach by sampling. Besides, I am sensing that MCMC would be the more appropriate method to used when sample size (observation) is limited. Does it make sense?

Comment: Several points: (1) VB produces an approximate posterior distribution (2) EM is used for the hyperparameters only (3) MCMC is used to sample from the exact posterior distribution and (4) sample size is not connected with the use of VB versus MCMC.

Comment: I have two last questions. 1) What is the thing that are iteratively optimized using EM-like method in VB? Is it the hyperparameters (such as weight concentration) in posterior probability distribution? 2) What is the advantage of VB over simple EM? In what circumstance do we have to apply VB instead of EM?

Comment: (1) EM is used to find the (hyper)parameters of the pseudo-posterior distribution on the parameters of the model, based on the data; this is a type of empirical Bayes approach (2) VB produces a whole distribution on the .parameters, while EM only produces the maximum likelihood estimator.